# If inside while error

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
    vector<int>numbers;
    int numb = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j = i - 1;

    while (cin >> numb)
    {
        if (numb == numbers[j]) HERE IS THE PROBLEM!* 
        {
            cout << "Numbers repeated\n";
        }


    numbers.push_back(numb);

    cout << "numbers[" << i << "] = " << numbers[i] << endl;


    ++i;

}
```

/*** I don't understand why a exception, run time error, break or whatever it names.....................................................

Comment: First time in the loop, your index into the vector is `-1`.

Answer (score 4):

On the first iteration through the loop, `j` is -1. Accessing `numbers[-1]` is undefined behavior because the index is outside the bounds of the vector.

Indeed, accessing any index is out of bounds until you put something in the vector, so you cannot index `numbers` *at all* until you have called `push_back` on it at least once.

This code will display the message if the user enters a number already in the vector:

```
while (cin >> numb) {
    vector<int>::iterator found = std::find(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), numb);

    if (found == numbers.end()) {
        cout << "Numbers repeated" << endl;
    }

    // If you don't want duplicate numbers in the vector, move this statement
    // into an "else" block on the last "if" block.
    numbers.push_back(numb);
}
```

This code on the other hand will only display the message when a number was the same as the last number entered, that is, if sequential numbers are the same:

```
while (cin >> numb) {
    if (!numbers.empty() && numb == numbers.back()) {
        cout << "Numbers repeated" << endl;
    }

    numbers.push_back(numb);
}
```

Comment: @Hego Good catch, I was thinking of `std::map` which does have this method. I will update it the answer to use `std::find` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your numbers vector with initial data, or check to make sure j is withing in vector size. A vector is essentially an array, and like any array, you cannot go out of bounds.

```
if (j < numbers.size() && numb == numbers[j]) HERE IS THE PROBLEM!* 
{
    cout << "Numbers repeated\n";
}
```